# Can I mark an answer as a workaround instead of an accepted answer?

Tags: support, answers, accepted-answer

I recently submitted a question. No one posted an answer to my question, but someone posted a workaround that was sufficient for me in this particular case.

Is it possible to mark his answer as a 'workaround' instead of accepting it as the answer?  Or should I just accept his reply as the answer and move on?

For some reason I thought I once saw 'Accept as a workaround' as an option on Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there is no such thing.

Author of a question can either accept one of the answers, or not - there is no "semi accept" feature.

So if the answer was useful, upvote it. If it did not fully solve the problem, do not accept it. Leave a comment explaining it it you want, for others to know as well, and that's it.

Once a question got an answer with positive score, it is removed from the "Unanswered" section of the site, even without any accepted answer.

Comment: OK thanks, I'll do that.

Answer (score 3):

In this specific case, I'd go for the "what you need, not what you want" approach.

A workaround is still a solution that presumably got you the end result you needed. In the absence of other answers, select it and comment that its a workaround, and how it did and didn't help.

Should a better answer turn up in future, you're always free to change the answer you have selected as the correct one.

Comment: much more wordy, didn't quite match my intent, too much handholding